# How can a URL redirection be detected in MFC?

Tags: c++, url, mfc, http-redirect

Using **HttpSendRequest()** I am able to navigate to web pages from MFC. Some URLs I am trying to visit are not valid, but certain servers, instead of sending error 404, are just redirecting to another page.

I am not sure how I can detect this redirection .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`404` is the HTTP status code for "URL entirely unknown". Redirect is another status code, `301`. You get this via `HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE`.

BTW, this isn't MFC but the basic WinInet functionality.